# Magento 2 set NOINDEX for layered navigation page

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

How can I set robots :

```
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
```

for layered navigation results in Magento 2?

I have searched the internet but there's no information to be found for this pretty important feature.

Comment: Try posting on magento.stackexchange.com to attract the right expertise.

Comment: Thanks, however magento.stackexchange.com is dead..

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer in below links:

> https://www.mageworx.com/wiki/magento-2-robots/
>
> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127138/meta-noindex-follow-in-magento-2-1

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. However it does not explain how to set it for layered navigation results